# Placing Snake in C

Tags: c

i am trying to do a basic snake game . I have a 
board  `char board[N][N]={{'\0'}};`
And i want to place my snake who has to be first line with the head at 0;0
and the body at 0;1 and 0;2. To track the tail and the body (for later for moving the snake) i create a 2D array for the coordinates of the snake .

```
int coord_percent[2][N*N] = { -1 };

coord_percent [0][0] = 0;
coord_percent [1][0] = 0;

coord_percent [0][1] = 0;
coord_percent [1][1] = 1;

coord_percent [0][2] = 0;
coord_percent [1][2] = 2;

int  size_percent = 3;
```

So now im calling a function to place the snake :

```
void place_snake (char board[N][N],int coord_snake[2][N*N],int size_snake) {

    int i;
    board[coord_snake[0][0]][coord_snake[1][0]] = '%'; // the head will always be the first in the array_coord

    for (i=1 ; i<size_snake ; i++) {
        board[coord_snake[0][i]][coord_snake[1][i]] = '*';

    }

}
```

I dont know where is my mistake ...
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: `int coord_percent[2][N*N] = { -1 };` only initializes `coord_percent [0][0] = -1` and all other element to to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Using a 2D array for the snake coordinates isn't a good idea, since you'll have to traverse the entire 2D array in order to figure out where the snake is.

It is better to use a [deque](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/) or [circular queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) to implement the snake.

Then your snake's body segments are arranged conceptually as:

```
C D E F G H I
```

To move the snake forward you unpaint the part of its body on the right (`I`) and add a part of the body on the left (`B`), to get:

```
B C D E F G H
```

In your code you will replace the capital letters by the 2D coordinates of the snake's body segments.

Comment: I didnt want to traverse the entiere 2D array, just wanted to remove the tail and add one more so i saw this only way to know where was the snake before the tail ... Maybe im thinking wrong can you please explicit more your exemple ??

Comment: @BellahsenRaphael To put it another way: instead of creating a 2D array that tracks the 1D position in the snake for each location in the arena, create a 1D array that tracks the 2D position in the arena for each snake segment.

Comment: I think that OPs 2D array is an array of (x,y) coordinates (2 coordinates x (N*N) points), but +1 for the circular array suggestion.

Comment: @Lou: Now that I look again, I see that you are right.

Answer (score 1):

@Richard is right that a circular queue is the best approach to keeping track of points, but you should make your life easier by starting from something like this:

```
typedef struct
{
    int x; int y;
} 
Point;

typedef struct
{
    Point segments[MAX_LEN];
    int length;
}
Snake;
```

Because then the `draw` function is much simpler:

```
void draw(Snake *snake)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < snake->length; i++)
    {
        Point seg = snake->segments[i];
        board[seg.x][seg.y] = '*';
    }
}
```

Of course the main point is to have a head pointer which will iterate over the `points` array so that you can easily remove the tail and add head.

Comment: its look like indeed a lot easier but dont think im allow to use this at this point ... there is no easily standard method for my method ?